Failed to resolve: com.vivekkaushik.datepicker:datePickerTimeline:0.0.4
The error am getting is this
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.vivekkaushik.datepicker:datePickerTimeline:0.0.4.


build.gradle
implementation 'com.vivekkaushik.datepicker:datePickerTimeline:0.0.4'

Please help me solve the problem or guide me on any other Android Date Picker Library that provides a calendar as a horizontal timeline
I tried chanigng the version but same problem persists, I also tried to google but found out the github repo for the library had been archived by the owner.

You need to find the repo that's hosting the artifact.
I found it for you: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vivekkaushik.datepicker/datePickerTimeline
You need to add maven repo to your list of repos in your gradle build file to search there as well in addition to android standard ones.
Interestingly the download stats shows that no one is using it, so be careful about adding this dep to your project.

Than you for your response Jahan but after adding the maven repository it's still not resolving the problem. In the site you shared they haven't shared the implementation

How else could I go about this please

@SaruniDavid That's bad! I recommend building and publishing it on you local maven repo under ~/.m2 or preferably publish it to your company Nexus or JFrog repository.
